# How to align amsmath matrices and make them look cleaner

Tags: amsmath, matrices, alignment, tabularray

I have no idea how to align these matrices or how to make them look cleaner. They look very messy, does anyone know how I can align the matrices and make them look cleaner please?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb} 
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{nicefrac} 
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
% Alternative formatting
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.in}  
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.in} 
%\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in} 
%\setlength{\textheight}{9in} 
%\setlength{\voffset}{-.5in}

\begin{document}
\[\ begin{bmatrix}A|I\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}[ccc|ccc]
        1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix} \]

    \sim
    \begin{bmatrix}[ccc|ccc]
        1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix} 
    \sim
    \begin{bmatrix}[ccc|ccc]
        1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & -2 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0\\ -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}
    \sim
     \begin{bmatrix}[ccc|ccc]
        1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & -2 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix} 
    \sim 
     \begin{bmatrix}[ccc|ccc]
        1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & -2 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}
    \end{bmatrix} 
 \sim
     \begin{bmatrix}[ccc|ccc]
        1 & 0 & -1 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\0 & -2 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}
    \end{bmatrix} 
    \sim
     \begin{bmatrix}[ccc|ccc]
        1 & 0 & -1 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\0 & -1 & 1 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}
    \end{bmatrix} 
    \sim
         \begin{bmatrix}[ccc|ccc]
        1 & 0 & -1 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\ 0 & -1 & 1 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0
    \end{bmatrix}
    \sim
         \begin{bmatrix}[ccc|ccc]
        1 & 0 & -1 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & \nicefrac {1}{2}
    \end{bmatrix}  
    \sim
         \begin{bmatrix}[ccc|ccc]
        1 & 0 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}  & \nicefrac{1}{2} & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & \nicefrac {1}{2}
    \end{bmatrix} 
    \sim
    \begin{bmatrix}[ccc|ccc]
       1 & 0 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}  & \nicefrac{1}{2} & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & \nicefrac {1}{2}
    \end{bmatrix} 

    \[ \begin{bmatrix}I|A^-\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}[ccc|ccc]
       1 & 0 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}  & \nicefrac{1}{2} & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & \nicefrac {1}{2}
       \end{bmatrix} \]
\end{document}
```

How it currently looks:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

You can first of all use `align*`. Also, fixed width columns make the display much more symmetric.

Since I'd not use `\nicefrac` even under physical threat, I changed it into `\nf` so you can, if you really want to, replace it again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, array}

\newcommand{\nf}[2]{#1/#2}
\newenvironment{mybmatrix}
 {\left[\begin{array}{@{}*{3}{w{c}{1.5em}}|*{3}{w{c}{1.5em}}@{}}}
 {\end{array}\right]}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}A\mid I\end{bmatrix}
&=
  \begin{mybmatrix}
  1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{mybmatrix}
 \sim
  \begin{mybmatrix}
  1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{mybmatrix} 
\\[1ex]
&\sim
  \begin{mybmatrix}
  1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & -2 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0\\ -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{mybmatrix}
 \sim
  \begin{mybmatrix}
  1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & -2 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1
  \end{mybmatrix} 
\\[1ex]
&\sim 
  \begin{mybmatrix}
  1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & -2 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \nf {1}{2} & 0 & \nf {1}{2}
  \end{mybmatrix} 
 \sim
  \begin{mybmatrix}
  1 & 0 & -1 & \nf {1}{2} & 0 & \nf {1}{2}\\0 & -2 & 2 & -1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \nf {1}{2} & 0 & \nf {1}{2}
  \end{mybmatrix} 
\\[1ex]
&\sim
  \begin{mybmatrix}
  1 & 0 & -1 & \nf {1}{2} & 0 & \nf {1}{2}\\0 & -1 & 1 & \nf {1}{2} & \nf {1}{2} & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \nf {1}{2} & 0 & \nf {1}{2}
  \end{mybmatrix} 
 \sim
  \begin{mybmatrix}
  1 & 0 & -1 & \nf {1}{2} & 0 & \nf {1}{2}\\0 & 1 & 0 & \nf {1}{2} & 0 & \nf {1}{2}\\ 0 & -1 & 1 & \nf {1}{2} & \nf {1}{2} & 0
  \end{mybmatrix}
\\[1ex]
&\sim
  \begin{mybmatrix}
  1 & 0 & -1 & \nf {1}{2} & 0 & \nf {1}{2}\\0 & 1 & 0 & \nf {1}{2} & 0 & \nf {1}{2}\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \nf {1}{2} & \nf {1}{2}
  \end{mybmatrix}
 \sim
  \begin{mybmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & \nf {1}{2}  & \nf{1}{2} & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0 & \nf {1}{2} & 0 & \nf {1}{2}\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \nf {1}{2} & \nf {1}{2}
  \end{mybmatrix} 
\\[1ex]
&\sim
  \begin{mybmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & \nf {1}{2}  & \nf{1}{2} & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0 & \nf {1}{2} & 0 & \nf {1}{2}\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \nf {1}{2} & \nf {1}{2}
  \end{mybmatrix} 
=\begin{bmatrix}I\mid A^{-1}\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think there are two serious problems with your code. First, you should be inserting explicit line breaks in the long formula. This may be accomplished by employing an `align*` environment instead of `\[ ... \]`. Second, the `bmatrix` environment does *not* know what to do with the `[ccc|ccc]` option and therefore dumps it into the first cell of the bracketed matrix. I suggest fixing this issue with a bespoke environment called `mybmatrix` below.

This answer is strictly about the typographical aspect of the OP's query. I haven't checked the OP's math at all...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,nicefrac} 
\allowdisplaybreaks % allow page breaks in 'align' and 'gather' environments
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % text block: 9in x 6.5in

\newenvironment{mybmatrix}%
   {\left[ \begin{array}{@{} rrr|rrr @{}}}%
   {\end{array} \right]}

% increase the vertical separation between rows of an 'align*' environment:
\addtolength{\jot}{2pt} % optional

\begin{document}

\noindent
Given:
\[
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}} 
    A & I
    \end{array}\right]
    = 
    \begin{mybmatrix}
         1 &  1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
         1 & -1 &  1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
        -1 &  1 &  1 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{mybmatrix} 
\]
We find that
\begin{align*}
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}} 
    A & I
    \end{array}\right]
    &\sim
    \begin{mybmatrix}
         1 &  1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
         1 & -1 &  1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
        -1 &  1 &  1 & 0 & 0 & 1
    \end{mybmatrix} \\ 
    &\sim
    \begin{mybmatrix}
         1 &  1 & -1 &  1 & 0 & 0\\
         0 & -2 &  2 & -1 & 1 & 0\\ 
        -1 &  1 &  1 &  0 & 0 & 1
    \end{mybmatrix} \\
    &\sim
     \begin{mybmatrix}
        1 &  1 & -1 &  1 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & -2 &  2 & -1 & 1 & 0\\ 
        0 &  2 &  0 &  1 & 0 & 1
    \end{mybmatrix} \\ 
    &\sim 
     \begin{mybmatrix}
        1 &  1 & -1 &  1 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & -2 &  2 & -1 & 1 & 0\\ 
        0 &  1 &  0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}
    \end{mybmatrix} \\ 
    &\sim
     \begin{mybmatrix}
        1 &  0 & -1 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\
        0 & -2 &  2 & -1 & 1 & 0\\ 
        0 &  1 &  0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}
    \end{mybmatrix} \\ 
    &\sim \begin{mybmatrix}
        1 &  0 & -1 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\
        0 & -1 &  1 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0\\ 
        0 &  1 &  0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}
    \end{mybmatrix} \\ 
    &\sim \begin{mybmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -1 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\
        0 & 1 &  0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\ 
        0 & -1 & 1 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0
    \end{mybmatrix} \\
    &\sim \begin{mybmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -1 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\
        0 & 1 &  0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\ 
        0 & 0 &  1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & \nicefrac {1}{2}
    \end{mybmatrix} \\  
    &\sim \begin{mybmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}  & \nicefrac{1}{2} & 0\\
        0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\ 
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & \nicefrac {1}{2}
    \end{mybmatrix} \\ 
    &\sim \begin{mybmatrix}
       1 & 0 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}  & \nicefrac{1}{2} & 0\\
       0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\ 
       0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & \nicefrac {1}{2}
    \end{mybmatrix}
\end{align*}
We have thus established that
\[
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}} 
    I & A^{-1}
    \end{array}\right]
    = \begin{mybmatrix}
       1 & 0 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}  & \nicefrac{1}{2} & 0\\
       0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2}\\ 
       0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \nicefrac {1}{2} & \nicefrac {1}{2}
    \end{mybmatrix}
\] 

\end{document}
```